# Programmatically set button background color removes margin and rounded corners

Tags: android, button, background-color

This is how I create an 5x5 grid of buttons of even size:

```
buttons_in_row = 5;
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons_in_row; i++) {
            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            for (int j = 0; j < buttons_in_row; j++) {
                Button btn = new Button(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
                btn.setLayoutParams(params);
                btn.setText("B " + (j + 1 + (i * buttons_in_row)));
                btn.setId(j + 1 + (i * buttons_in_row));
                btn.setWidth(width / buttons_in_row);
                btn.setHeight(width / buttons_in_row);
                btn.setOnClickListener(this);

                row.addView(btn);
            }

            layout.addView(row);
        }
```

[image]

When I set the background color to something else than the default, this is what happens:

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

use

```
btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFAA0000));
```

You can use different values according to your required colour.If you want to know the constant values of colours, you can refer [the documents](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/graphics/Color.html).

Also , you can programmatically set the shade of the entire button using the PorterDuff multiply mode. This will change the button colour rather than just the tint.

For example for a red shaded button

```
btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

For a green shaded button

```
btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Hope this helps.